# Problem with Pear mail adding line breaks on x-headers

Tags: php, pear

I was wondering if anyone here with experience of PEAR mail or PEAR mail queue could help me out with this.

I am working on creating a bulk mailing service using PEAR and am adding X-headers to give information on where and when people signed up.

So am am trying to create a X-header similar to this:

```
X-Subscription: Subscribed on 2010/09/01, via web form, by 92.8.196.121 from http://mydomain.com/signup.htm
```

However after I pass the headers to PEAR mail mime and queue they are formatted with a line break at certain points so they end up looking like this:

```
X-Subscription: Subscribed on 2010/09/01, via web form, by 92.8.196.121 from
     http://mydomain.com/signup.htm
```

I have tested this by creating a few different headers and the line break always comes after a certain amount of characters but I cannot seem to find any code in PEAR which would cause this.

Does anyone here have any experience of this? Or know of a way I could fix this?

Thanks for looking

Comment: For anybody else having trouble with this I found the solution was to edit the maximum string length in the `encodeHeader` function inside mimePart.php

Comment: is this causing a problem for you?  Technically, even headers have a maximum length.  If they need to run long, starting the next line with a tab performs a continuation of the previous.

Answer (score 2):

The "issue" of headers being split onto multiple lines is correct behavior according to [RFC 822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822.txt), section "3.1.1. LONG HEADER FIELDS":

> For convenience, the field-body  portion  of  this  conceptual
>   entity  can be split into a multiple-line representation; this
>           is called "folding".  The general rule is that wherever  there
>           may  be  linear-white-space  (NOT  simply  LWSP-chars), a CRLF
>           immediately followed by AT LEAST one LWSP-char may instead  be
>           inserted.

As described in [What is the email subject length limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592291/what-is-the-email-subject-length-limit), [RFC 2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html) suggests to keep a line length of 78.