# Resolving 'The specified string is not in the form required for a subject.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, mailmessage

I have a class that sends an Email (MailMessage) but I get the following error:

> "The specified string is not in the form required for a subject."

Is there a handy dandy method to sanitize the strings or do I have to write my own?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

I haven't personally tried it, but according to [this](http://blog.dotsmart.net/2008/02/15/systemnetmail-the-specified-string-is-not-in-the-form-required-for-a-subject/), you only need:

```
subject = subject.Replace('\r', ' ').Replace('\n', ' ');
```

or something equivalent.

Internally, the `MailMessage` class will check the subject with:

```
if (value != null && MailBnfHelper.HasCROrLF(value)) 
{
   throw new ArgumentException(SR.GetString(SR.MailSubjectInvalidFormat));
}
```

So the only limitation (for now) happens to be the presence of `CR` or `LF`.

Comment: Thank you for this.  But gotta say -- is there any reason that Microsoft couldn't just *say* that newlines are not allowed?

Comment: You know documentation is hard ;-) The reason it is not allowed is most likely, that CRLF has very special purposes in the message format (see [RFC5322](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322)) and they didn't wanted to bother automatically changing user's data, but rather fail and let have him do it manually (like shown above).

Comment: Further note `subject = subject.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");`

Comment: @Nae, the correct way (judging by the source code of MailMessage) is to replace BOTH `\r` and `\n` characters. Your solution will only work in some cases...

Answer (score 9):

Also there is a limit of 168 characters so you should check for that too.

UPDATE: sorry this is complete bullshit :)
It must have been a line break in my case.

Comment: Is there any documentation to link to on this?

Comment: I don't think so, we just figured it out by trial and error. I could be wrong, you are welcome to try it yourself and post the result.

Comment: Sounds good to me, I was just curious how you came by the answer (and such an odd value at that). Already +1 - a solution is a solution :)

Comment: @mikenelson - I wonder why there is such a small limit. Imagine if this is used in SSIS (An ETL tool), your package could simply fail because of this limitation.

Comment: I tested this with over 900 characters and it works fine

Answer (score 4):

For VB.NET

```
subject = subject.Replace(vbNewLine, "")
```

Comment: I assumed `subject = subject.Replace(vbCr, " ").Replace(vbLf, " ")`

Answer (score 1):

I know this has already answered, but it goes:

First, you need to trim the subject then account for the subject max length ([What is the email subject length limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592291/what-is-the-email-subject-length-limit)):

```
subject = subject.Trim();
subject = subject.Substring(0, Math.Min(subject.Length, 78));
```

This will remove any new lines or empty spaces at the beginning and the end. Then Substring is used to restrict the subject length.

Comment: Length over 78 chars is not a problem here, \r\n presence is, but nice to have this answer too.