# Charcter Limit for Mail to function in Gmail When the body and subject is included

Tags: html, email, browser, outlook, gmail

I am trying below function in sending email and same content works fine when i receive email in outlook but when i see in gmail it does not even show the link on the Tag.Can you some body help me how can i fix the issue in Gmail and is there any limit for mailto function in gmail?

Want to approve some but not all repairs in the repair quotation

Answer (score 0):

The standard (mailto protocol) doesn't define a maximum length, leaving implementation up to browsers and mail clients ([IETF RFC 2368](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068)). But you can find some limitations described for browsers and mail clients on the [Effective maximum mailto: body lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473959/effective-maximum-mailto-body-lengths) thread.

Also, take a look at the [MAILTO max-length of each internet browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317429/mailto-max-length-of-each-internet-browsers/33041454#33041454) page.