# sendig mail to multiple recipients with html Mailto: not working c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to send with 1 HTML link a mail to multiple (300) recievers...

This link doesn't work. It do nothing when i press the link.
mailto:person1@domain.com;person2@domain.com.......'
Is there a maximum length on mailto: attribute ?

```
var employees = db.Employees;
            List<string> Emaillist = new List<string>();
            string email="";
            foreach (var item in employees)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemEmail) == false)
                    {
                    Emaillist.Add(item.Email.ToString());
                   

                }
                
               
            }
         
            foreach (var item in Emaillist)
            {

                email = email + item+";";

              
            }
        
            var outlookmail = "mailto:"+ email;
            return outlookmail;
```

Comment: `link doesn't work` what do you mean by this?

Comment: i mean the outlook not opening on clicking the link . but when i try with few email example 10 receivers the outlook opening .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317429/mailto-max-length-of-each-internet-browsers