# How to change the mailer Content-Transfer-Encoding settings in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, postfix-mta

The 'Content-Transfer-Encoding' setting is set to '7bit' by default.
The mail server Postfix is breaking down the email header by bunch of 1000 caracteres, meaning that if you have a long email (using HTML for example), you end up having spaces in the middle of your text or links. (See this thread for more info: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/postfix-users/message/273296)

Following the Rails ActionMailer documentation (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html), adding the following code to my app file should make it, but it doesn't work:

`ActionMailer::Base.default 'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'quoted-printable'`

I still end up with the default:

```
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="--==_mimepart_50166adf1e043_1b9810829142282d";
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

My email look like that:

```
def new_registered_user(user_id) 
    @user = User.find(user_id)

    set_locale @user.locale

    mail(
      :subject => i18n_subject,
      :to => @user.email_with_name
    ) do |format|
      format.text { render :layout => 'text_email' }
      format.html
    end
  end
```

Any idea on what else should I change?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found that setting the (undocumented) transport_encoding on the Mail object works:

```
m = mail(...)
m.transport_encoding = "quoted-printable"
m.deliver
```

I could not get the documented approach of setting  the Content-Transfer-Encoding via ActionMailer to work.

My environment: rails (3.1), mail (~> 2.3.3)

Comment: fyi, email line length is limited to 998 characters. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592291/what-is-the-email-subject-length-limit

Comment: thank you very much, so there is no other option than adding breakline (\r\n) for long emails

Comment: Indeed. There MUST be a CRLF every 998 characters. That said, depending on your content encoding, you can avoid putting the CRLF in the content itself.

Comment: Thanks so much! for question and answer.. what a tricky problem this was!

Instead of `m.transport_encoding = "quoted-printable"` I use `m.transport_encoding = "base64"` because we have to send mail in foreign chars and according to wikipedia:  "Base64 ... is the more sensible choice for binary formats or text in non-Latin based languages." from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable

Comment: p.s. I was lucky to find this question. I had the same problem of spaces in my text and links but had no idea that the content_transfer_encoding had to be altered. For the benefit of others it might be good to add in the title "Rails random spaces in email text and links" or something.. or maybe this comment alone will help the search results.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a custom mailer class, you can set it as a default option in your mailer class, as described in the [documentation of ActionMailer::Base](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionMailer/Base)

```
class Notifier < ApplicationMailer
  default 'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => '7bit'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this problem recently. Rails was defaulting to `quoted-printable`, but that was causing rendering problems for me in a webmail client. New lines were rendered as `=0D`, which the webmail client rendered incorrectly.

My solution to this was the alter the content encoding of only the html part since I'm also sending a separate text part and do not want to change its encoding. The `html` method takes a `content_transfer_encoding` argument, avoiding the need for a temporary variable:

```rb
mail do |format|
  format.text { ... }
  format.html(content_transfer_encoding: '7bit') { ... }
end
```

The documentation references using `default 'Content-Transfer-Encoding' ...` but that only works when not calling the `mail` method directly.