# pre-populating email subject with a long sentence

Tags: html, email, mailto

I am trying to pre-populate email subject with a rather long sentence. The mail client cuts half of it off though. Is there a way around it?

Comment: It's possible that it's the client that has the limit.

Comment: <A HREF="mailto:example@email.com?subject=My rather long subject line&body=message here">click here</a>

Ah, just realised that it cuts it off on the &
It doesn't seem to like neither & nor &amp;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is shown here [What is the email subject length limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592291/what-is-the-email-subject-length-limit#1592310), there is an intrinsic limitation for each subject's line, which is of 998 (the maximum allowed), with a suggestion to limit to 78 characters.

The answer I linked suggests to add a carriage return, in order to overcome the limit.

So, instead of having as header:

```
Subject: This is a test
```

You should have:

```
Subject: This
is a test
```

You can try with the urlencoded version of a carriage return, which is: `%0D`

It's not the best solution (since having the subject on multiple lines is not the best), but it could be a good workaround to this limitation.

Comment: is there a special code for '&'?
it doesn't like it, nor the &amp;

Comment: For '&' it's '%26'. Check the full list here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Answer (score -2):

we can do it by

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=your%20subject>
```

no more chaeracters than a 998.avoid returns

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: oops,bad reading. well it has the limit of around a 1000 characters,you may avoid returns.But surely that will not help you much.But i believe a long subject is least preferable