# Can't get SMTP client email code to work

Tags: c#, smtpclient

I have this code I wrote:

```
public static void sendemail(string strMsgBody, string strMsgSubject, ref List<queryResults> offenders)
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(fromEmailAddr@mycompany.com, myEmailAddress@mycompany.com);
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Port = 25;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Host = "hostname";
        mail.Subject = "My Subject Line";
        int intDashCounter = 0;
        string dashMailBody = strMsgSubject + Environment.NewLine;
        foreach (queryResults offender in offenders)
        {
            if (offender.strType == strMsgBody && offender.blnReported == false)
            {
                dashMailBody = dashMailBody + offender.strUniqueID + Environment.NewLine;
                offenders[intDashCounter].blnReported = true;
            }
            intDashCounter++;
        }
        mail.Body = dashMailBody;
        client.Send(mail);
    }
```

It was working at one point in time but now it does not work. For the life of me I can't track down what I changed to make it so that it doesn't work. Sorry for this one, I know its probably some stupid little thing but can someone give me a nudge in the right direction with this code?

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: sorry for leaving that out, it just doesn't do anything. The program goes on but it doesn't send out an email.

Comment: Do you not need some credentials somewhere?  You have use default turned off, but do not define any to use.

Comment: The only difference between what you have and what I have in my working code is a USING block around my client, and I never set useDefaultCredentials.  If the default for useDefaultCredentials is true then it must be credentials.  Is this in a try/catch at some point?  I get an exception when I run mine because my local environment isn't allowed to send through our email relay, but my staging and production environments work.  But you do not mention getting an exception.

Comment: I'm guessing port 25 has been blocked. That's pretty common these days due to spam problems. (I also don't see how your `new MailMessage` could work with the addresses specified that way -- is this your real code?)

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured it out but the solution I found doesn't make logical sense. I shortened the value being passed in to the variable `strMsgSubject` and for some reason the method now sends out emails.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592291/what-is-the-email-subject-length-limit)